# Converting Avro Binary String to Json

Tags: java, avro

I have a String in Avro Binary Format. I want to convert the String to json. Can someone please guide me ?. I tried using the solutions available online It did not work.

```
public String avroToJson(byte[] avro) throws IOException {
        boolean pretty = false;
        GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = null;
        JsonEncoder encoder = null;
        ByteArrayOutputStream output = null;
        try {
            reader = new GenericDatumReader<GenericRecord>();
            InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(avro);
            DataFileStream<GenericRecord> streamReader = new DataFileStream<GenericRecord>(input, reader);
            output = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            Schema schema = streamReader.getSchema();
            DatumWriter<GenericRecord> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<GenericRecord>(schema);
            encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, output, pretty);
            for (GenericRecord datum : streamReader) {
                writer.write(datum, encoder);
            }
            encoder.flush();
            output.flush();
            return new String(output.toByteArray());
        } finally {
            try {
                if (output != null) output.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

I am converting the my String to byte array using getBytes() and passing it to this function. I am getting this exception. 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.avro.InvalidAvroMagicException: Not an Avro data file.

Comment: [json-avro-converter](https://github.com/allegro/json-avro-converter/blob/master/README.md)

Answer (score 6):

Avro specifies a binary format for serializing one object, but also a [Object Container File](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.9.1/spec.html#Object+Container+Files) (also known as data file) which can hold many objects in a useful way for file access.

`DataFileStream` expects the container file, but from your description, it looks like you have a single serialized instance.

You probably want something like:

```java
  public String avroToJson(Schema schema, byte[] avroBinary) throws IOException {
    // byte to datum
    DatumReader<Object> datumReader = new GenericDatumReader<>(schema);
    Decoder decoder = DecoderFactory.get().binaryDecoder(avroBinary, null);
    Object avroDatum = datumReader.read(null, decoder);

    // datum to json
    String json = null;
    try (ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream()) {
      DatumWriter<Object> writer = new GenericDatumWriter<>(schema);
      JsonEncoder encoder = EncoderFactory.get().jsonEncoder(schema, baos, false);
      writer.write(avroDatum, encoder);
      encoder.flush();
      baos.flush();
      return new String(baos.toByteArray(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
  }
```

Note that this means you *must* know the schema in advance to deserialize the binary data.  If it *were* an Avro data file, you could get the schema from the file metadata.